gaps between zeros of solutions to $y''+\frac{y}{x}=0$
Let $u$ be a non-zero solution to $y''+\frac{y}{x}=0, x>1$.
Let $z_1<z_2<z_3<\dots$ the zeros of u.
a) Show that $z_{n+1}-z_{n} \asymp \frac{z_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ Where $A \asymp B$ means that there are two constants $C_1,C_2$ s.t. $C_1 \cdot A \leq B \leq C_2 \cdot A$ for all $n \geq 1$.
b) Conclude that $z_n\asymp n^\frac{3}{2}$.
The problem with this exercise:
If the second conclusion is true, then $z_{n+1}-z_{n} \asymp \sqrt{n}$ but $\frac{z_n}{\sqrt{n}}\asymp n.$ Which is a problem.
Can anyone help understanding what did I get wrong? Or if this is a mistake in the exercise.

Did you try to get some numerical confirmation? Use an ODE integrator with event support and set it into "root registration mode". Compute the fractions of both side in each claimed or speculated asymptotic relationship. With 20 roots, say, the resulting table should indicate quite clearly if the columns become constant or at least stay bounded.

The asymptotic WKB approximation is $y(x)=C\sqrt[4]{x}\sin(2\sqrt{x}+D)$. Then $2\sqrt{z_n}+D=n\pi$. Then $4z_{n+1}-4z_n=2\pi(n\pi-D)+\pi^2$ so that $z_{n+1}-z_n\asymp \frac\pi2\sqrt{z_n}$, which is also not close to the claims.

You get the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem where if $c^2\le q(x)\le d^2$ on some segment $[a,b]$, then $y(x)$ will oscillate faster than $\sin(c(x-a))$ and slower than $\sin(d(x-a))$. Thus if $a$ is a root of $y$, then the next root will be between $a+\frac{\pi}{d}$ and $a+\frac{\pi}{c}$.
In the current context this gives
$$
z_n+\sqrt{z_n}\pi\le z_{n+1}\le z_n+\sqrt{z_{n+1}}\pi.
$$
The last can be transformed as a quadratic (equation) inequality
\begin{align}
(2\sqrt{z_{n+1}}-\pi)^2&\le 4z_n+\pi^2,\\
\sqrt{z_{n+1}}\le \frac{\pi+\sqrt{4z_n+\pi^2}}2
&=\sqrt{z_n}+\frac{\sqrt{4z_n+\pi^2}-(2\sqrt{z_n}-\pi)}{2}\\
&=\sqrt{z_n}+\frac{2\sqrt{z_n}\pi}{\sqrt{4z_n+\pi^2}+(2\sqrt{z_n}-\pi)}.
\end{align}
So in the end, indeed
$$
z_{n+1}-z_n≍\sqrt{z_n}\pi.
$$
For asymptotics one can orient on the solution of the corresponding differential equation $\dot z=k\sqrt z$ to see that $\sqrt{z}\sim kt$, so
$$
\sqrt{z_{n+1}}\simeq\sqrt{z_n+\pi\sqrt{z_n}}=\sqrt{z_n}\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{z_n}}}=\sqrt{z_n}+\frac{\pi}{2}+O(z_n^{-1/2}).
$$
which is fine for asymptotics as $z_n$ is very large for large $n$.
Summing that up
$$
\sqrt{z_{n+m}}\simeq \sqrt{z_n}+m\frac\pi2+...
$$
There is room for tightening up these bounds and approximations, and expand further on what the next terms would be. The last paragraph might be redundant as the first estimate of $\sqrt{z_{n+1}}$ might already give this bound. Or it might improve it from upper bound to asymptotic behavior.
As for claim a), at this stage the above would suggest
$$
z_{n+1}-z_n\asymp \pi\sqrt{z_n}=\frac{\pi z_n}{\sqrt{z_n}}\asymp\frac{2z_n}{n},
$$
which is not exactly the claim.
